# join same rails models twice, eg people has_many clubs through membership AND people has_many clubs through committee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, has-and-belongs-to-many, polymorphic-associations

Models:
 * Person
 * Club

Relationships
 * Membership
 * Committee

People should be able to join a club (Membership)
People should be able to be on the board of a club (Committee)

For my application these involve vastly different features, so I would prefer not to use a flag to set (is_board_member) or similar.

I find myself wanting to write:

People
has_many :clubs :through => :membership # :as => :member? :foreign_key => :member_id?
has_many :clubs :through => :committee # as (above)

but I'm not really sure how to stitch this together

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
has_many :committee_clubs, :through => :committee, :source => :clubs
has_many :membership_clubs, :through => :membership, :source => :clubs
```

Comment: you will have to change the People model to include commitee_clubs_id and membership_clubs_id as well